# auto close angular material sidemenu

Tags: angular, angular-material

Is there any way to auto close the sidemenu if i go away from sidemenu. I have tried with directive that contains hostlistener with mouseenter and mouseleave but how can i get that i am not on the sidemenu.

You can demonstrate here : https://stackblitz.com/angular/qrnojyvlgbx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.html

But look like stackblitz is also broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mouseleave event on sidenav element to close the sidenav.

First, reference that sidenave using a variable, like:

> <mat-sidenav #sidenav>

and then use the mouseleave event, like:

> <mat-sidenav #sidenav (mouseleave)="sidenav.close()">

Check this example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-sidenav?file=app/sidenav/sidenav.component.html

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav  mode="side" class="example-sidenav"  opened="true"
        (mouseleave)="sidenav.close()">
        <div class="logomain">Logo Part</div>
        <mat-nav-list>
          <mat-list-item routerLink="1" routerLinkActive="active" >
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>person</mat-icon>
            <div fxFlex="10"></div>
            <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
              <h5 class="lead">About</h5>
            </div>
          </mat-list-item>
    
          <mat-list-item routerLink="2" routerLinkActive="active">
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>settings</mat-icon>
            <div fxFlex="10"></div>
            <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
              <h5 class="lead">Services</h5>
            </div>
          </mat-list-item>
    
          <mat-list-item routerLink="3" routerLinkActive="active">
            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>local_phone</mat-icon>
            <div fxFlex="10"></div>
            <div *ngIf="sidenavWidth > 6" class="sidenav-item">
              <h5 class="lead">Contact</h5>
            </div>
          </mat-list-item>
        </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>
```